# Comparando arrays angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Estou a criar um dispositivo para cell... so que tive o seguinte problema: preciso comparar se uma conta não foi paga, e enviar um aviso...

contas q devem ser pagas todos meses.. caso não encontre o nome no outro array gerar o aviso

```
[{"tipo":0,"classe":"Entrada","nome":"111","categoria":"Meu salario","cor":"MediumSeaGreen"}]
```

lista de conta para conferencia se foi paga...

```
[{"classe":"Entrada","data":"10-11-2016","dia":"Qua","tipo":0,"categoria":"Meu salario","cor":"MediumSeaGreen","nome":"111","comentario":"","total":5},{"classe":"Saída","data":"10-11-2016","dia":"Qua","tipo":1,"nome":"1","categoria":"Despesa fixa variavel","cor":"DodgerBlue","total":1}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o método `forEach` para passar por cada elemento da `array` e dentro dele fazer a verificação.

Exemplo:

```
var obj1 = [{"tipo":0,"classe":"Entrada","nome":"111","categoria":"Meu salario","cor":"MediumSeaGreen"}]
var obj2 = [{"classe":"Entrada","data":"10-11-2016","dia":"Qua","tipo":0,"categoria":"Meu salario","cor":"MediumSeaGreen","nome":"111","comentario":"","total":5},{"classe":"Saída","data":"10-11-2016","dia":"Qua","tipo":1,"nome":"1","categoria":"Despesa fixa variavel","cor":"DodgerBlue","total":1}]

//Verificação
angular.forEach(obj1, function(item1, key) {
    angular.forEach (obj2, function(item2, key) {
        if(item1.categoria == item2.categoria) {
            item1.pago = true;
        }
    })
})
```

O que acontece é que, nesta parte: `angular.forEach(obj1, function(item1, key)` para cada elemento da `array obj1` ele é identificado através de `item1`, então você pode acessar cada propriedade através de `item1.propriedade`. `key` se refere ao `$index` do objeto dentro daquela `array`, caso seja necessário usar, está ali. A mesma lógica se aplica à segunda `array`.

Note que estou fazendo 2 `angular.forEach`, pois você precisa navegar navegar por 2 `array`, logo, para cada elemento da primeira `array`, você precisa comparar com cada elemento da segunda `array`.

O tratamento de `item1.pago = true` foi um exemplo, mas é ali que você aplica o status de 'Pago' conforme melhor para você.

Comment: tive outros problemas não foi so esse mais funciono tive que reseta o array novo em alguns momentos pois isso e dentro de uma função... ai acontece manipulação, então teve uns probleminhas mais no geral e isso msm vlw :D

Comment: Beleza, mas o importante é você entender a lógica e aplica-la em seu método. Se isso funcionou, maravilha! Que bom que ajudei!